# Implicitly Convert Type

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, dao

i am doing this in WPF and i am using entity-framework .

this is my query code in my CRUD class file :

```
 public class QuestionHint
    {
        public int? QuestionNo { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
        public int? ActivityID { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
        public int? TaskID { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
        public string Answer { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
        public string QuestionContent { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
        public string joined { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
        public string joinOption { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 

    }

        public IList<QuestionHint> GetListKeys(int listTask, int listActivity)
    {
        IList<QuestionHint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID }).ToList().Select(g => new QuestionHint()
        {
            QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo,
            ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID,
            TaskID = g.Key.TaskID,
            joined = String.Join(" ",
                g.OrderBy(q => q.questionhintID)
                 .Select(i => i.QuestionContent + "[" + i.Answer + "]")),
            joinOption = String.Join(" ",
                   g.OrderBy(q => q.questionhintID)
                    .Select(a => "[" + a.Option1 + "," + a.Option2 + "]"))


        }).Where(x => x.TaskID == listTask && x.ActivityID == listActivity)
            //.Take(50)
    .ToList();

        return lstRecords;
    }
```

i  call this in code behind :

```
 private DAO.DAOQuestionHint qh = new DAO.DAOQuestionHint();

    public MainWindow2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateQuestion(1, 5);
    }

    private void PopulateQuestion(int activityID, int taskID)
    {


        IList<QuestionHint> lstQuestionHints = qh.GetListKeys(taskID, activityID); // ERROR

        //codes here...
        }
```

i am getting this error in the code behind of my xaml.cs :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

iStellar is the name of the project. DAOQuestionHint is the name of the CRUD class file.

There is no error in the CRUD class file , i use the same query to retrieve records in the other project and it works well , don't know why it don't work in here.

Comment: I don't understand.. your return type is `IList<QuestionHint>` and your variable is `IList<Model.questionhint>`... They seem incompatible

Comment: You should return `IEnumerable<T>` (or at least `ICollection<T>`) unless you need to truly access items by their index. And, even then... you can always call `ToList()` in the section of code that receives an enumeration of items. `List<T>`, and even `IList<T>` are not recommended as a return value.

Comment: And, your LINQ function doesn't make sense... you are doing a `GroupBy` on a new anonymous objects... none of them will ever be grouped. Then, you `ToList()` right after which is unnecessary. All you really need is to first, do the `Where()` statement, then the `Select()` statement... this is the most efficient way.

Comment: but it work when i tried to retrieve the records and display them in a grid view in other web project . I tried to change QuestionHint to Model.questionhint , it gave me lots of error .

Answer (score 2):

You're using different capitalization for the generic argument in each example - `IList<QuestionHint>` in `GetListKeys()` and `IList<Model.questionhint>` in `PopulateQuestion()`.  I'd guess these refer to similarly named but different types.

Comment: i noted that , but i can't write QuestionHint istead of Model.questionHint

Comment: @user2376998 If QuestionHint is in a namespace called 'Model' that's fine, but it would have to be `Model.QuestionHint`, not `Model.questionhint`.  If you right click on each and click 'Go to Definition', do they go to the same place?

Comment: Opps i mislook the QuestionHint , its actually a separate class , see my edits above.